# How to enable using css url function with loofah?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, sanitize

What I already tried:

```
Loofah::HTML5::WhiteList::ACCEPTABLE_CSS_FUNCTIONS.add 'url'
Loofah::HTML5::WhiteList::ACCEPTABLE_CSS_PROPERTIES.add 'background-image'
```

But

```
Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.new.sanitize_css 'background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png);'
```

returns ""

Testing with rgb:

```
Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.new.sanitize_css 'background-image: rgb(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png);'
```

returns

```
'background-image:rgb(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png);'
```

With `Loofah::HTML5::Scrub.scrub_css` I have the same results.

Lofah version : 2.13.0

Rails version : 6.1.4.4

Tested in Rails Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it doesn't work because the url filter [is hardcoded](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah/blob/a6922ce26eaddaa4d638b5df66c018d002d33b75/lib/loofah/html5/scrub.rb#L86).